# Invert "bake sounds to f-curves" f-curves?

Tags: animation

Basically, I am trying to rotate the mouth bone of a model to simulate talking, and to do that I want to bake the sounds to f-curves, but the mouth moves up, not down. Any idea on how to invert the f-curves or the movement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pose mode go to pose menu, animation, bake action.

Then in curves editor select all and press S, Y, -1, Enter.

Comment: i cannot find curves editor, can you please tell me where I can find it? the only thing close to that would be the graph editor, but idk

Comment: Yes, graph editor, select the channel, select all baked keyframes and scale.

Comment: that did not work :(

Comment: nvm it worked i did it like a dumbass

Comment: sorry and thank you

Comment: well shit now the mouth is fucked :(

Comment: If useful please marke the answer as accepted.